# calculating MPC orbital uncertainty parameter U

Tags: asteroids, comets, celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to understand how the orbital [uncertainty parameter 'U'](https://minorplanetcenter.net//iau/info/UValue.html) introduced by the Minor Planet Center (MPC) is actually calculated for minor bodies. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_parameter) gives the formulae to be used in what appears to be a two-step process of the calculation. The first step involves plugging in a variable referred to as  $\Delta \tau$, the uncertainty in the perihelion time in days, to the first formula to obtain what is referred to as the in-orbit longitude runoff, $r$.

I'm having trouble finding/ computing $\Delta \tau$, the uncertainty in the perihelion time in days for a given minor body. I'm aware that the uncertainties of all the six orbital parameters of a minor body is available at the [JPL Small Body Database](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/). Anyone has some idea how to work out the uncertainty in the perihelion time in days from the data available from the JPL Small Body Database ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of JPL SBDB's elements for asteroid [2021 GT2](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=K21G02T).
The perihelion time **tp** is shown as a Julian date on the TDB timescale with uncertainty in days.

[image: Screenshot of orbital elements from JPL SBDB]

If I evaluate the [MPC formulas](https://minorplanetcenter.net/iau/info/UValue.html):

```
RUNOFF = (dT * e + 10 / P * dP) * ko / P * 3600 * 3

U = INT(ln(RUNOFF)/CONS)+1  (0 <= U <= 9)
```

with dT = 0.00022344 d, e = 0.23291, P = 0.93321 y, dP = 0.00028335 d,
ko = 0.98561°, and CONS = 1.4868,
I get RUNOFF = 35.227 and U = 3, matching JPL's "condition code" for this asteroid.
MPC's "uncertainty" for [2021 GT2](https://minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?utf8=%E2%9C%93&object_id=K21G02T) is also 3.

In some cases JPL and MPC have different U values for the same asteroid, but the reason isn't obvious to me.

*Edit*: Shortly after the first version of this answer,
a close approach to Earth by 2021 GT2 allowed new observations,
which decreased dT by a factor of 2, dP by a factor of 8, and U by 1.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply ! I had overlooked the information available for osculating orbital elements in JPL SBDB.
I too have have noted some differences between the U values between JPL and MPC and from what I recall the differences were in the order of 1. I reckon this is probably due to some latest observations/ larger observational arc incorporated into one of these sites, while the other was using non-latest data. However this is only a speculation at this point.